# How can I decrypt this simple XOR encryption for Lua Script?

Tags: encryption, lua

```
key=gg.prompt({"Enter Password"},{""},{"text"})
[1]local a=load((function(b,c)function bxor(d,e)local f={{0,1},{1,0}}
local g=1;local h=0;
while d>0 or e>0 do h=h+f[d%2+1][e%2+1]*g;
d=math.floor(d/2)e=math.floor(e/2)g=g*2 end;
return h end;
local i=function(b)
local j={}
local k=1;
local l=b[k]
while l>=0 do j[k]=b[l+1]k=k+1;
l=b[k]end;
return j end;
local m=function(b,c)if#c<=0 then return{}end;
local k=1;
local n=1;
for k=1,#b do b[k]=bxor(b[k],string.byte(c,n))n=n+1;
if n>#c then n=1 end end;
return b end;
local o=function(b)local j=""for k=1,#b do j=j..string.char(b[k])end;
return j end;
return o(m(i(b),c))end)
({150642,122783,122295,135436,146969,90016,86043,150619,80488,111860,122502,86813,106235,136554,126669},key))
if a then a()else gg.alert("Wrong Password")end
```

Can I get the code which can simply decrypt the ciphertext which is encrypted by the above code.

Comment: This code will crash for any password.  Are these numbers correct: `{150642,122783,122295,..` ?

Comment: Yes these numbers are correct but i didnt include all the numbers and the password is 2210 .

Comment: Are there more than 150000 numbers in that array?

Comment: Yes, it might be. I use Microsoft word to count the character and it says 784,996 characters with 8.753 lines.

Comment: The code you posted is actually the decryptor.  That very long array of numbers is an encrypted code. You are asking "how to decrypt". To decrypt and show decrypted code (but not run it), just replace `local a=load` with `print`, remove the last line `if a then...` and run the script.

Comment: Error(s), warning(s):
lua5.3: source_file.lua:10: attempt to compare number with nil
stack traceback:
 source_file.lua:10: in local 'i'
 source_file.lua:21: in function <source_file.lua:1>
 source_file.lua:1: in main chunk
 [C]: in ?

Comment: Actually, I wanted a program which can decrypt/encrypt that code so I can understand and alter it as I want. I got the above error when I replace local a=load with print. You have given me some link on my previous question so it helps me to encrypt and decrypt in that fashion. I want the same kind of solution if possible.

Comment: `attempt to compare number with nil` This is because you didn't include all the numbers.